# Make a directory named with date

Tags: shell, date, mkdir

I want to make a directory with the name being the day. I have this variable:

```
[Desktop]: $dia
21/02/16
```

created this way:

```
dia=$'date +%d/%m/%y'
```

I'm trying to make a new directory this way:

```
mkdir "$dia"
mkdir: date +%d/%m: No such file or directory
```

and

```
mkdir $dia
mkdir: date: File exists
mkdir: +%d/%m: No such file or directory
```

but it creates a directory named date.

How can I make this? Thanks!

Comment: I assume, you are using `bash`. Functions use parentheses, i.e. `dia=$(date +<format>)`. You are using the string `date +%d/%m` for the dirs.  Do NOT use slashes in your date format, as they are for subdirectories! Check the variable by `echo $dia` and you will understand the problem better.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to make a directory with day and time

```
now=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")
mkdir ${now}
```